# Real time video recording frames processing

Tags: video, ffmpeg, android, opencv

Recently I have been working on an Android camera with lots of features using camera2 and OpenCV, and now I want to record a video with custom resolution, for example if my device support 1920×1080 video recording resolution then I want to be able to record video with resolution 1920×800 for instance, i.e. to crop frames height a bit.

See : if I have this by default

[image: Normal video]

Then I want to be able to crop video frames height a bit from above and bottom so i would have eventually video like this:

[image: Processed real time video with height cropped]

I have searched a lot and didn't find any result, I just found that camera2 api doesn't support this feature.
I would be grateful for any response.

Comment: Are you saying you're trying to edit this with in the android phone, or doing this on a computer? Because i'm 100% sure any of this can be done via a PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you need to rethink what you want to achieve. While cropping video is easy with FFMpeg (see e.g. [this](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4563/how-can-i-crop-a-video-with-ffmpeg) question), you will end up with an App that doesn't run in realtime on low-power phones and will be a huge battery drain on those that can manage.

You have a few options:

- transport the video to a server and do the processing there
- Just use the full-sized video but cover the unused parts in your app

Comment: What about using openGL and shaders to crop each frame?